# Applying CSS for some words in a link_to link

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml, link-to

My link is

```
= link_to '+++ Sync categories', "cats/sync", :remote=>true
```

And I need to apply some CSS for the part '+++'

It works when I do it like this, but I have a space between the '+++' part and the rest which doesn't redirect to the link.

```
%span#create_cat_arrow.arrow +++
= link_to 'Sync categories', "cats/sync", :remote=>true
```

How can I apply the CSS only for the '+++' part?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= link_to "cats/sync", :remote=>true do
  %span.myclass '+++ '
  Sync categories
```

or if you want in line styles

```
= link_to "cats/sync", :remote=>true do
  %span{style: "color: #c0c0c0"} '+++ '
  Sync categories
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I couldn't figure out how to pass a parameter to sycn with this style. Can u help me with this as well? Thanks in advance

Comment: link_to("cats/sync?key=value", :remote => true) do..., or if you are using your path helpers as dictated by your routes, you should be able to use link_to(cats_sync_path(:my => parameter), :remote => true) do...